Hooking up a ceiling light
I’m trying to install a ceiling light (no fan). This is my 3rd install, so I thought I knew what I was doing. There are 4 total wires out of the ceiliing junction box. 1 red, 1 black, 1 white and 1 copper. The way I have hooked that up previously is I capped off the red, and black to black, white to white and copper to green screw. The red I believe is for a fan control (should it be a fan/light combo). When I hooked everything up, my breaker tripped. I must be doing something wrong here. Any advice? Thanks!
PS this junction box has a red and black because of the ability to hook up a fan/light.



Why are you not using a simple single pole switch?  Does the light need a 3way?

i didn’t hook this up. this is a new house. how should i do this? thanks!
